# The font not loaded to my html page

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-face

I have this code in my CSS file.

```
style.css

@font-face {
  font-family: "KTishk";
  src: url('../fonts/KTishk.ttf');
  }
```

and this is my webpage's structure

- Root

  - index.html
  - **css**

    - style.css
  - **fonts**

    - KTishk.ttf
  - **subfolder**

    - test.html

**My problem**: In the index.html page, the CSS and font load correctly and work but in the **test.html** (located in the subfolder directory), the CSS loads but the font is not loaded and isn't applied.

The code used for loading the stylesheet:

```
index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?version=2" >

test.html 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css?version=2" >
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. What do the Developer Tools in  your browser say? Look at the Network tab: Are the URLs loaded correctly? Look at the Console: Are there error messages? Look at the Elements Inspector: Is the rule that is supposed to apply that font family really applied to the element you think it should be? Is the rule overridden by something else?

Answer (score -1):

Do this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Griffy;
  src: url(Griffy-Regular.ttf);
  font-style: italic;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Griffy', cursive;
}
```

you also need to specify bold , italic etc
for your reference [beautiful-fonts-with-font-face](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/beautiful-fonts-with-font-face/) and [w3-font-resource](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-resources)

Comment: The URL you give to `@import` needs to be that of a stylesheet.

Comment: @Tofiq try this , it may help

Comment: "you also need to specify bold , italic etc" — Why?

Comment: "w3school-font-resource" – Don't confuse W3Schools (purveyors of low quality references and tutorials) with the W3C (who write language specifications).